# Jboss 7 , How to add a custom log level in standalone.xml

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jboss7.x

My application is running in `Jboss As 7 server`. I want to segregate all logs from a class (say `me.test.ClassA`) with log level `CDR` to a particular log file(say `cdr.log`).

How can I achieve this in `jboss As 7`. I know by using `log4j.xml` this is possible. But I want to use the `standalone.xml` so that I can change the log level at runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't separate log messages based on a custom level. You can use a known level and/or a logger name though.

Assuming in your `me.test.ClassA` you get a logger via `Logger.getLogger(me.test.ClassA.class)` or an equivalent where you end up with a logger named `me.test.ClassA` you can define that logger to write to a specific handler.

Example CLI to add a file handler:

```
/subsystem=logging/file-handler=cdr:add(append=true,autoflush=true,file={"relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir","path"=>"cdr.log"})
```

Create the logger

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=me.test.ClassA:add(level=INFO,handlers=["cdr"])
```

This will send all log messages from a logger created with the name `me.test.ClassA` to the file `cdr.log` as well as the `server.log` file and the console. If you don't want the messages to be sent to `server.log` and the console then in the add operation for the logger add the attribute `use-parent-handlers=false`

Comment: Thank you. But I need to segregate the logs with level CDR only to a separate file. I am wondering why jboss hide this facility provided by log4j.

Comment: Because JBoss AS does not use log4j. You could use log4j a configuration instead in your deployment, but it wouldn't log anything server supplied dependencies. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F

Comment: If JBoss is not using log4j why we have to give exclusion of `<module name="org.apache.log4j" />` in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. I understand that by giving this exclusion we are telling `JBoss` to not to use the `Jboss log4j` configs.

Comment: No, that excludes the supplied version of log4j which is added to all deployments by default. JBoss AS adds a log4j module by default for convenience. It basically treats log4j like a facade. The LogManager of log4j is not used.